# CloudFormation: How to update a particular without updating the entire stackset?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

*This might be a little difficult to express but please feel free to ask any questions if you need any clarifications.*

There are multiple resources and infrastructure which is being managed by cloudformation. There is another set of resources which will be managed by CDK.Their permissions are managed by cloudformation.

**Problem :

> Now, to give cdk we need to edit the Iam role managed by CDK. This is a very simple configuration change which will involve the update of StackSets and the impact of update of StackSets is huge which I want to avoid.**

- The change is simple which is not an issue but adding this change will involve update of stacksets, which has a huge impact, I am simply looking for a way to avoid update of stacksets even for such simple change.
- After looking into details of the issue, There is a also a concern that updating even the small resources would require giving junior developers admin access to update the role.

Can someone guide me as to how to go around with this.

Comment: Sorry, what is your problem? If the change in configuration of IAM role is so simple, why not do it?

Comment: The change is simple not an issue but adding this change will involve update of stacksets, which has huge impact, I am simply looking for a way to avoid update of stacksets even for such simple change.

Comment: Some updates can be done in place, without re-creation of resources. So check if this is the case in your setup.

Comment: I have updated the question. There is problem giving access to junior devs just to allow them to update the current role with stacksets.

Comment: Sadly your question is too confusing. I do not think you will get a precised answer to your issue.

Comment: I will try rephrase it in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that you don’t want to touch the CloudFormation template because is too big and complicated, why don’t you create another stack that creates just a new role, and so switch the old role to this new role in CDK?

Comment: Since I am not so experienced with cloudformation, creating another stack would also require us to give junior devs admin permission to make changes to the account even for such a small change.

Comment: Well, create it through the console then :)

Comment: @JatinMehrotra "would also require us to give junior devs admin permission" - I think you have much more serious problems with the setup of your AWS accounts and their users. Even if you find the solution to this problem, in the long term, you will be experiencing more and more issues due to bad design from the start. Maybe it would be good idea to go back to the beginning, and re-think the entire setup.

Comment: I think in my mind there is an option to create new access for developers at OU level, and add minimum permissions to the access